# netlogo flocking procedure along specific color patches

Tags: netlogo

I've only recently started working with netlogo and I'm attempting to adapt the flocking model to reflect processional group movement along a defined street network. The flocking procedure is working but I'm having difficulty confining the movement to the street network which are black patches.

I have defined the street patches from the GIS extension

```
ask patches
  [ ifelse gis:intersects? streets self [
    set street? true
    ]
    [
      set street? false
    ]
  ]
  ask patches with [ street? ]
  [ set pcolor black ]
```

I have attempted to have the turtle avoid certain patches using the below example, but the result is ping-pong movement

```
if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 3 = gray + 4 [set heading heading - 180]
```

I'm not certain if there is a better way to make the turtles move along only the black street patches using the flocking code, posted below.

```
to move-serapis
  ask serapis [ process ]
    repeat 5 [ ask serapis [ fd 0.2 ] display ]
  tick
end

to process                           
  find-serapidmates
  if any? serapidmates
    [ find-serapis-neighbor
      ifelse distance serapis-neighbor < .5
        [ separate ]
        [ align
          cohere ]
  ]
end

to find-serapidmates                
  set serapidmates other serapis in-radius 12 ;vision
end

to find-serapis-neighbor 
  set serapis-neighbor min-one-of serapidmates [distance myself]
end

to separate  ;; turtle procedure
  turn-away ([heading] of serapis-neighbor) 19.5
end

to align  ;; turtle procedure
  turn-towards average-serapidmates-heading 19.75
end

to-report average-serapidmates-heading                   
  let x-component sum [dx] of serapidmates
  let y-component sum [dy] of serapidmates
  ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
    [ report heading ]
    [ report atan x-component y-component ]
end

to cohere                                                 
  turn-towards average-heading-towards-serapidmates 10
end

to-report average-heading-towards-serapidmates  ;; turtle procedure
  let x-component mean [sin (towards myself + 180)] of serapidmates
  let y-component mean [cos (towards myself + 180)] of serapidmates
  ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
    [ report heading ]
    [ report atan x-component y-component ]
end

to turn-towards [new-heading max-turn]                    
  turn-at-most (subtract-headings new-heading heading) max-turn
end

to turn-away [new-heading max-turn]  
  turn-at-most (subtract-headings heading new-heading) max-turn
end

to turn-at-most [turn max-turn]  
  ifelse abs turn > max-turn
    [ ifelse turn > 0
        [ rt max-turn ]
        [ lt max-turn ] ]
    [ rt turn ]
end
```